# how to convert range of values in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want these values to be converted to a range of 1-100
`A= [0 -24 14 34 8 41 55...]`

> with minimum value of -30
>   and maximum value of 57

Answer (score 1):

You can do standard normalization, like this:

```
A = [0 -24 14 34 8 41 55 -30 57];
minimum = -30;
maximum =  57;
B = 1 + 99 * (A - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
```

After running, `B = [35.1379 7.8276 51.0690 73.8276 44.2414 81.7931 97.7241 1.0000 100.0000]`